Some Slurm output environment variables are empty
I have the following SBATCH script:
#!/bin/bash

## Job Misc
#SBATCH --job-name=dummy_job    # Job name
#SBATCH --output=dummy_run.out  # name of output file
#SBATCH --error=dummy_run.err   # name of error file
#SBATCH --partition=GPU         # Partition to run on

## Node config
#SBATCH --nodes=1 # node count
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2 # total number of tasks per node

## Job Config
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4 #  cpu cores to use per task


export NCCL_DEBUG=INFO

# Cleans out the modules loaded in interactive and inherited by default 
module purge

# Load software
module load CUDA/11.8.0

# prints the date and time
date

##### Number of total processes ##### 
echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "
echo "Nodelist:= " $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST
echo "Number of nodes:= " $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES
echo "Ntasks:= "  $SLURM_NTASKS
echo "Ntasks-per-node:= " $SLURM_NTASKS_PER_NODE
echo "cpus := " $SLURM_TRES_PER_TASK
echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "

nodes=( $( scontrol show hostnames $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST ) )
nodes_array=($nodes)
head_node=${nodes_array[0]}
head_node_ip=$(srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 -w "$head_node" hostname --ip-address)

echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "
echo "Nodes:= " $nodes
echo "nodes_array:= " $nodes_array
echo "head_node:= "  $head_node
echo "head_node_ip:= "  $head_node_ip
echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "

echo "Running  training session..."

# Run python script
srun torchrun \
--nnodes=$SLURM_NNODES \
--nproc_per_node=$SLURM_NTASKS_PER_NODE \
--rdzv_id=$RANDOM \
--rdzv_backend=c10d \
--rdzv_endpoint=$head_node_ip:12345 \
/PATH/TO/PYTHON_SCRIPT/train_distributed.py

echo "Training session completed."

The problem
When I submit the job, in the error I get:

return int(nproc_per_node) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''


So I added some echo statements to see what the actual return value of these global variables are, here's the result:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
Nodelist:=  gpu-0-3
Number of nodes:=  1
Ntasks:=  2
Ntasks-per-node:= 
cpus := 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
Nodes:=  gpu-0-3
nodes_array:=  gpu-0-3
head_node:=  gpu-0-3
head_node_ip:=  NODE_IP
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 

I did try various things but they still returns an empty value, while the other variables return the correct value.
More info about slurm global variables can be found here.
Is it possible that the admin of the HPC did not enable these variables to be exported?

Have you tried using the --export switch to explicitly pass the values?

@XZhang The default value for export is ALL but I did try to set it explicitly as well. Unfortunately, it did not solve the issue.

Try removing the comments add the end of the #SBATCH lines.
